# How to Bulk import Product Reviews in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, programmatically, review

I have a list of reviews with email id, how can I bulk import Product Reviews into Magento?

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below url with answer try to do via custom script
https://stackoverflow.com/q/12255463/5187928

Comment: How to add ratings also?

Comment: Yes will do with ratings

Comment: The link you given only reviews, can i get some idea about how to import ratings also. Thank You.